# Rendered frame rate is different than the original footage's

Tags: rendering, frame-rate

Everytime I render a video or animation, it is converting to 1000fps? The original footage is 30fps. Why is it changing? How do I adjust the setting?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80052/blender-reads-some-videos-frames-incorrectly-duplicates-skipping/80053#80053

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the frame rate is set to 30 here.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it is but it still renders out at 1000. Well it renders out at 30fps but then I check the property details and it says 1000fps. Problem being if I bring the file back into Blender it has 1000fps..

Comment: Can you upload your blend file or the 1000fps video? It's not an issue I've seen before.

Answer (score 0):

I have literally had to upload every Blender video I render to Youtube, and then download it to get the proper frame rate.[image]

Comment: There is no need to do that. There are plenty of transcoders you can use (like ffmpeg, for example). My guess is that you want to edit something recorded with software that uses variable frame rate. Blender cannot deal with those sources, It needs a constant frame rate.  Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86954/can-blender-vse-sync-the-video-and-audio-with-vfr-strips

Comment: So the transcoder will correct the frame rate? If so, What free transcoder would you recommend?

Comment: [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).